# Disable buttons in Jquery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I use a jQuery UI dialog that is made from HTML supplied from server. Code:

```
 $("<div id='pastedial'>" + result.htmlPasteDialog + "</div>").dialog({
                maxHeight: "85%",
                minWidth: 700,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function () {
                        // do cancel
                    },
                    "Paste!": function () { 
                       // do action
                    }
                // some other config

            });
        }
```

To dialog elements I attach event handler that validates the dialog. This works well. The validation function is just another function of page, that addresses dialog items based on their IDs that I know directly.

How I can address dialog's buttons from external function (that belongs to page) so I can disable actions if dialog is not validated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access and disable the buttons with something like this:

```
function xxx(){
  $('#pastedial').find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(1)').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Comment: That will work, but you should use `.prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: `$('#pastedial').dialog('widget').find('whatever button').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 3):

I use this, which is almost the same as Babblo, but searching for the caption of the button instead.
Hope it helps.

```
function test() {
    $("#pastedial")
        .next(".ui-dialog-buttonpane")
        .find("button:contains('Paste!')")
        .button("option", "disabled", true);
}
```